# Merging JSON outputs of parallel states in Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a parallel block in a Step Function. The input to the parallel block looks like

```
{ "a": null, "b": null }
```

The 2 parallel states are **populateA** and **populateB**. The output from **populateA** is

```
{ "a": "A", "b": null }
```

And the output from **populateB** is

```
{ "a": null, "b": "B" }
```

The output from the parallel block is an array

```
[ { "a": "A", "b": null }, { "a": null, "b": "B" } ]
```

How do I merge the two into

```
{ "a": "A", "b": "B" }
```

Answer (score 1):

If PopulateA always only populates the value of a and PopulateB only the value of b, you can use a Pass state with Parameters (instead of the Result field) after your Parallel State to combine the inputs. Parameters allow you to transform your input by specifying key-value pairs using JSONPath.

Here is an example State Machine:

```
{
"StartAt": "Parallel",
"States": {
    "Parallel": {
        "Type": "Parallel",
        "ResultPath": "$.CombinedOutput",
        "Next": "MergeOutputs",
        "Branches": [{
                "StartAt": "populateA",
                "States": {
                    "populateA": {
                        "Type": "Pass",
                        "Result": {
                            "a": "A",
                            "b": null
                        },
                        "End": true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "StartAt": "populateB",
                "States": {
                    "populateB": {
                        "Type": "Pass",
                        "Result": {
                            "a": null,
                            "b": "B"
                        },
                        "End": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "MergeOutputs": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
            "a.$": "$.CombinedOutput[0].a",
            "b.$": "$.CombinedOutput[1].b"
        },
        "Next": "EndState"
    },
    "EndState": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. If you're using YAML to describe the state machine on Serverless framework, make sure you don't use '-' for each parameter, since this will make an individual object for each.

Comment: Just a note for people coming here if you have the slightly different case where PopulateA not only populates a but also creates an object with other fields and PopulateB updates a field on that object, then you can't use this solution to make it work, but you can write a simple lambda to merge the two outputs.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input and outputs (for PopulateA and populateB) and your expected final output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not possible (currently) to do that without additional state. You can add additional Task after Parallel state which will merge array elements.

The code of the additional task would look like this (Python):

```
def merge_dicts(a, b):
    result = a.copy()
    for key, value in b.items():
        if value is not None:
            result[key] = value
    return result

def handler(event, context):
    result = {}
    for item in event:
        result = merge_dicts(result, item)
    return result
```

`handler` takes output from the Parallel states and merges it into single dictionary. The state should be directly after Parallel.

Keep in mind that this code handles only flat-dict (not nested ones) so it will work in simple cases but not in complex ones (I've added it here only to show the general idea).

Comment: So, you're controlling steps of the state machine with python code. How do you know in which step the state machine is?

Comment: @sphoenix It does not matter in this case because logic is always the same. State Machine creator has to simply create Task State succeeding Parallel state with specific Lambda ARN